# how can i check to see if a box is checked onclick an event that alerts user if not

Tags: javascript, validation, dom

The code below should do 4 things.

1) Check to see if a checkbox is checked if not alert user to select an answer

2) Check to see if the answer is check if so change btn to green if not turn btn red

3) Check

4)

```
<div class="theBigBox">
    <h3>1. How can you make a text bold in HTML ?</h3>
        <div class='answerBox'>
            <input type="checkbox" class="question1"  id="qOne" value="1"> (A) &lt b &gt text &lt b &gt
            <input type="checkbox" class="question1"  id="qTwo" value="2"> (B)  Both <br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="question1"  id="qThree" value="3"> (C) &lt strong &gt text &lt strong &gt
            <input type="checkbox" class="question1"  id="qFour" value="4"> (D) Neither<br>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="ansSubmit" onclick=testSubmit()"> Check Your Answer</button>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="testTip" onclick="myTip()"> Ask For A Tip</button>
        </div>

function ansSubmit(){
  var ans = document.getElementsById('qThree');
  var ansCheck = ans.checked;
  var checkbox=document.getElementsClassName("question1");
  var okay=false;

  for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
  {
    if(checkboxs[i].checked)
    {
      okay=true;
      break;
    }else if(ans.check == false){
      alert("Please select an answer");//if check is not checked then alert a warning
    }else if(ansCheck !== true ){
      document.getElementById("testSubmit").style.backgroundColor = "red";//if ans not checked then turn button red
    }else if{
      document.getElementById("testSubmit").style.backgroundColor = "green";//turn button green
    }else alert("Please check a checkbox");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few typos in your code.  The first change was in your javascript, you had two variables, `checkbox` and `checkboxs`.  By making it just `checkboxs` you can go through them all as an array.

The next thing is `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are the correct way using the javascript DOM to access the elements by either id or classname.

```
<div class="theBigBox">
  <h3>1. How can you make a text bold in HTML ?</h3>
  <div class='answerBox'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="question1" id="qOne" value="1"> (A) b text
    <input type="checkbox" class="question1" id="qTwo" value="2"> (B) Both
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="question1" id="qThree" value="3"> (C) strong text strong
    <input type="checkbox" class="question1" id="qFour" value="4"> (D) Neither
    <br>
     <button id="ansSubmit" onclick="ansSubmit()">Click me</button> 
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="testTip" onclick="myTip()"> Ask For A Tip</button>
  </div>

<script>
function ansSubmit() {
    var ans = document.getElementById('qThree');
  var ansCheck = ans.checked;
  var checkboxs = document.getElementsByClassName("question1");
  var okay = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
      okay = true; //Only if one checkbox is checked set okay to true
     }
  }

  // Check if none of the boxes were checked
  // If none are checked, then throw an alert to select an answer and
  // set the background color of the button to red
  if (!okay) {
     document.getElementById("ansSubmit").style.backgroundColor="red";
     window.alert("Please select an answer");
  } else if(okay && ansCheck) { // if one checkbox is checked and the right answer is checked, set the background color of the button to green 
       document.getElementById("ansSubmit").style.backgroundColor="green";
  } else { // else, the user selected something but didn't select the right answer, tell them its the wrong answer
  window.alert("Wrong answer");
  }

}
</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc0dkegm/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much! the only thing i did was to check if the wrong ans was selected an alert, This worked perfectly now! I appreciate your help. i see i had a load of typos going back,i have to tighten up on those geesh

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I was able to help! You could always change from styling the color of the button to the background div that your answers are on top if you so desired.